# How do I center an image when I am merging it on to another image?

Tags: c#

I found some code online to merge images. I set it up and worked it out. I finally got it to work but the images that I am merging onto the blank image is not centered.

Here is the how it looks:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSelectImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFileLoc.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(txtFileLoc.Text);
            txtImgWidth.Text = img.Width.ToString();
            txtImgHeight.Text = img.Height.ToString();
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                txtOutputPath.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
                //string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnResize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        string format = "MMMddyyy";
        string imgdate = time.ToString(format);
        int Height = Convert.ToInt32(txtNewHeight.Text);
        int Width = Convert.ToInt32(txtNewWidth.Text);
        Image resultImage = new Bitmap(Height, Width, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage))
        {
            grp.FillRectangle(
                Brushes.White, 0, 0, Width, Height);
            resultImage.Save(txtOutputPath.Text + @"\" + imgdate + ".jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Image img = Image.FromFile(txtFileLoc.Text);

        }
        Image playbutton;
        try
        {
            playbutton = Image.FromFile(txtFileLoc.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }

        Image frame;
        try
        {
            frame = resultImage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (frame)
        {
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height))
            {
                using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    canvas.DrawImage(frame,
                                     new Rectangle(0,
                                                   0,
                                               Width,
                                             Height),
                                     new Rectangle(0,
                                                   0,
                                                   frame.Width,
                                                   frame.Height),
                                     GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    canvas.DrawImage(playbutton,
                                     (bitmap.Width / 2) - (playbutton.Width / 2),
                                     (bitmap.Height / 2) - (playbutton.Height / 2));
                    canvas.Save();
                }
                try
                {
                    bitmap.Save(txtOutputPath.Text + @"\" + imgdate + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) centering as such is just very simple math ..but.. b) make sure both images have the very same dpi settings!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to center an image when drawing on top of another image you need to calculate the position of an image (X,Y) which can be done as following:

```
int x = (bitmap.Width - image.Width) / 2;
int x = (bitmap.Height - image.Height) / 2;
```

Then you can just draw your image with

```
canvas.DrawImage(image, x, y, image.Width, image.Height);
```

Notice, this approach allows you to center an image regardless of whether it's smaller than the original bitmap or larger. When calculating the (X,Y) an one pixel rounding inaccuracy may occur so it would be beneficial to use Math.Round to correct that.

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response! It worked perfectly. Thank you.